# How can I make the transmute spell more useful for producing silver ore?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The [transmute spell](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Transmute_Mineral_Ore) allows you to convert any iron ore in your inventory into silver ore and any silver ore into gold ore.  This is pretty useful for turning a quick profit crafting jewellery.

However as it converts them in that order (1 iron --> 1 silver --> 1 gold) rather than repeating the conversion of iron to silver until you have no iron left than starting converting silver to gold, it is therefore awkward to make a large quality of silver.

Like everyone else, I've been forced to drop the silver ore crafted after each transmute, however as I'm on PS3 this is very clunky (requiring several button presses) and not entirely reliable (sometimes dropping random items instead of the silver when the menu position has changed for reasons unknown).

Has anyone found a more efficient way to do this?  I'd imagine on PC you could set up some kind of macro, is there anything similar I can do on PS3 to stop me going insane?

Comment: Just a word of advice: Don't bother with money - you'll find everything you need (including money and valuables) while questing/exploring.

Comment: afaik since you are on the PS3, its not possible.  But if you want silver for some reason, I'd recommend mining it from Sanuarach Mine or Cidhna Mine

Comment: @5pike No, that depends on your play style, and not everyone plays Skyrim the same. If you're like me and do more free-roaming than questlines, you need all the money you can get.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Strange, I typically stray away from quest and free-roam around the world, exploring dungeons, killing bandits etc. and I never had money problems (because I found so much stuff). The only problem I hat while playing skyrim, was finding enough iron ingots for forging.

Comment: @5pike Lots of ways to roam too. I think I spend too long exploring outside and passing up caves as time sinks to get rich, but the views are worth it.

Comment: the easiest way to get money in my opinion is creating powerful well crafted weapons (with a high smithing skill)and enchanting them (with a high enchanting skill) then selling them on only this requires that you level a lot to get your smithing and enchanting skills high enough :P

Comment: You could also mine silver ore or buy it and ingots. There is only one gold mine (why I marry Pavo in each playthrough) but several silver mines.

Answer (score 4):

Cast two copies of the spell at a time, one in each hand (not dual-casting with the perk; two separate casts). If both casts occur at the same time, you should only see one "Silver Ore Added" message, but two Iron from your inventory will have been turned into Silver. It doesn't seem like a huge improvement, but it does effectively double the rate at which you can convert from Iron to Silver.

Comment: I'll give this a go tomorrow and see if I can get it to work (although Hearthfire I'm probably better keeping the iron!!)

Comment: Gold? But that's not what the Questioner wants.

Comment: @NiteCyper Huh. It's a typo, and I'm amazed nobody's ever spotted it before now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a PS3 user myself, there is no other way I know of but to slave away at dropping the silver ore and then transmuting.

Comment: You can't create spells like in Oblivion. :'(

Comment: well I guess that's something that Bethesda wanted to nerf cus it kinda made Oblivion really easy but then again it was right near the end of a shit hard quest line and you had to be a high level to create good enough spells it made the game so much more complex and interesting not to mention the freedom in gameplay they should patch skyim with the ability in my opinion :P

Comment: why has this been downvoted I don't see any other way of giving a more constructive answer :s

Comment: It's been flagged as "not an answer" - essentially you've said "it would be good if we could do X but we can't" which isn't really an answer to the question.  However, "this isn't possible" is a valid answer.  Also people seem to dislike it when answers say "I think..." as opposed to being authoritative.  If you want to say something without giving it authority as an answer, a comment is usually more appropriate.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: I gave it a bit of an edit to make it read more confidently without changing what you said, and to cut out the guess about spell creating. That will probably head off any further downvotes!

Comment: i'll rephase the answer then haha cus its pretty clear that there isnt any other way of transmuting